# how do i get div childs from jquery/javascript in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to access to the div's child by using jquery's .eq() function, but it looks like something's wrong, despite the fact is not throwing an error, looks like when i do a .innerHTML to the desired child div element, nothing happens.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="status_container">
    <div class="status_item_wrapper">
        <div class="status_item_title">
            <span>TITLE 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="status_item_content">
            <table id="box-table"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="status_item_wrapper">
        <div class="status_item_title">
            <span>TITLE 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="status_item_content">
            <table id="box-table"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function doSomething(message) {
     var data = message.data;
     var index_container = 0;

     var container = $("#status_container").eq(0);
     var content_wrapper = container.eq(1); // this would be the content div of each child
     content_wrapper.html(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I thought this would get the "TITLE 1" status_item_wrapper div, and then, content_wrapper would contain the "status_item_content" object.

How am i supposed to reach the "status_item_content" div from the very first parent "status_container"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content_wrapper` is a jQuery object, as that is what `eq()` returns, and does'nt have an `innerHTML` method, you should use jQuery's `html()` :

```
content_wrapper.html( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

to return the native DOM element instead, you can use `get()`, and do :

```
var content_wrapper = container.get(1);
content_wrapper.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you've added `container`, there are some issues. `eq()` will get a certain element in a collection of elements based on a zero based index, and you're using an ID as a selector, so there should'nt really be a collection, as ID's are unique, and should only select one single element.

If you're trying to select the second child inside the `#status_container` element, you'd do

```
 var content_wrapper = $("#status_container").children().eq(1);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but didn't work with html() either :( look my edited code above. Don't know why this isn't working. Checked if the data was correct, but bleh since it's a test it's a "Hello world" string